# Django i18n_patterns does not match links with different language codes

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, url-pattern

I've been spending couple of hours already trying to understand what am I missing. I have the languages defined in the project settings file.

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('fr', 'French'),
)
```

Then I have the LocaleMiddleware listed in my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

And finally in my urls.py I have the following

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

...
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^about/$', 'about.view', {'template_name': {'en':'contact_en.html', 'fr':'contact_fr.html',},}, name='about'),
)
```

Now links /en/about work well, however links with /fr/about fail with the following error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in XXX.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: 
...
2. ^en/

The current URL, fr/about/, didn't match any of these.
```

Can anybody help me understand what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved the problem. Everything above is correct for regular project. However I forgot the fact that I wrote a middleware that patches the `request.urlconf` field dynamically to replace with the right URL conf. After looking into `LocaleMiddlware` code I found out that the middleware instead uses the `settings.ROOT_URLCONF` and thus was not looking into correct `urls.py`!

So if anybody does patch the `urls.py` don't forget to patch also the `ROOT_URLCONF`